# Vue bootstrap-vue throwing error after installation

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I am trying to add bootstrap Vue to a new project and after installation, it shows this error is there any fix to that?

> Failed to compile with 1 error
> 11:44:32  error  in
> ./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=7ba5bd90&lang=scss
>
> Syntax Error: SassError: Undefined variable.    ╷ 29 │
> -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba($black, 0); // 5    │                                     ^^^^^^    ╵   node_modules\bootstrap\scss_reboot.scss 29:37
> @import   src\assets\scss\vendors\bootstrap-vue\index.scss 4:9
> @import   src\App.vue 3:9                                       root
> stylesheet
>
> @
> ./node_modules/vue-style-loader??ref--8-oneOf-1-0!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-1!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--8-oneOf-1-2!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--8-oneOf-1-3!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader-v16/dist??ref--0-1!./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=7ba5bd90&lang=scss
> 4:14-419 15:3-20:5 16:22-427  @
> ./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=7ba5bd90&lang=scss  @
> ./src/App.vue  @ ./src/main.js  @ multi
> (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.1.4:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node
> (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js

My build looks like that

```
{
  "name": "bootstrap-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.11.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.17.3",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "mutationobserver-shim": "^0.3.7",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "portal-vue": "^2.1.7",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0-0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0-0",
    "sass": "^1.32.8",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "vue-cli-plugin-bootstrap-vue": "~0.8.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

bootstrap-vue currently does not support `vue 3.0`

See https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/5196

Answer (score 0):

In your App.vue, you need to import _custom.scss before bootstrap style sheet as it contains the referenced variables.

```
<style lang="scss">
    @import "~@/assets/scss/vendors/bootstrap-vue/_custom"; 
    @import "~@/assets/scss/vendors/bootstrap-vue/index";  
</style>
```

Note this error is not due to the use of Vuejs 3